# Picamera picture naming

Tags: python-2.7, camera, raspberry-pi

i am having a problem with picamera and python. All i am trying to do is take a variable name and then save a picture with that variable name concatenated with the .jpg file type.

```
import picamera
import time


camera = picamera.PiCamera()

camera.vflip = True
camera.hflip = True
itemname = raw_input ('what is the item name? ')
time.sleep(6)
camera.capture(itemname,'.jpg')
time.sleep(2)
camera.close()
print "done"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct syntax

```
import picamera
import time


camera = picamera.PiCamera()

camera.vflip = True
camera.hflip = True
itemname = raw_input ('what is the item name? ')
time.sleep(6)
camera.capture(itemname + ".jpg")
time.sleep(2)
camera.close()
print "done"
```